# Framework or CMS to build e-learning webapp

Tags: java, cms, framework, educational, slideshow

I'm searching for a framework or CMS that could provide me these features on a webapp:

- A way to create presentations (slides)
- A way to create multiple choice questions
- A way to create a course from these two types of items

I've seen there is Open Edx but it seems far too big for what I want.
Another solution would be to use reveal.js for the presentation part and develop the rest, but I would like to know if there already exists a better alternative?

I'm searching something in Java if possible.

Comment: If Moodle does not fit would you mind saying why?

Comment: I've not seen any way to add embedded slides into Moodle, except from Google Slides and I can't store the kind of data that will be present in the slides in another platform / website. It should be hosted on my server.

Comment: @Ereold - For slideshows in Moodle, I convert Powerpoint presentations into SCORM packages using the [iSpring Converter](http://ispringsolutions.com/). It's a free tool that generates HTML5 presentations from your Powerpoint, with the added advantage of also being SCORM compliant, so you can track your users' progress through them in Moodle (or any other LMS).

Answer (score 1):

[Moodle](https://moodle.org) is a "course management system" that seems to fit your purpose.

- [Plugin to integrate web presentations](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_revealjs) (based on [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/))
- Creatinge multiple choice questions is an established feature of the core Moodle
- Courses can be created from these items.

It is more lightweight than Open Edx, but written in PHP rather than Java. Open source.

Adding a multiple choice question:

[image: Moodle add multiple choice]

Example of a (rather ugly) Moodle slideshow:

[image: Moodle slideshow]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to moodle is to use a couple of drupal-based solutions, but non-java though. Not sure there are many java-based solutions for this.

e.g.:

1. [Opigno](https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno) or [Opigno LMS](https://www.opigno.org/en/features)

   > Opigno is used to create e-learning platforms of all sizes. The Opigno
   >   core is lean and mean, providing flexible building blocks and APIs to
   >   create a custom e-learning system. It uses Drupal 7 and contributed
   >   projects like OG, Quiz, Rules and Views.

The quiz module gives multiple-choice. There is a course entity for organising courses. There also drupal modules for slides.

2. Using native drupal modules like: course, quiz, gdoc_field, pdf_reader, etc to achieve a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Sakai](https://www.sakaiproject.org/documentation), [Olat](http://www.olat.org/) or [Atutor](http://www.atutor.ca/) are probably what you are looking for:
Sources:
https://webresourcesdepot.com/7-widely-used-and-open-source-e-learning-applications/
http://elearningchef.com/elearning-chefs-top-5-open-source-lmsystems/